# Rotate xtick labels of a specific subplot

Tags: python, matplotlib, seaborn, subplot, axis-labels

How to rotate in 90° the labels of X axis of subplot 222 (chart 2) and keep using sns.boxplot?

```py
fig = plt.figure(figsize=(12, 8))

# CHART 1
fig.add_subplot(221)
#sns.countplot(df_train['MSZoning'])
sns.boxplot(x='MSZoning', y='SalePrice', data=df_train)
                 
# CHART 2
fig.add_subplot(222)
#sns.boxplot(x='MSZoning', y='SalePrice', data=df_train)
sns.boxplot(x='Neighborhood', y='SalePrice', data=df_train)

# CHART 3
fig.add_subplot(223)
#sns.boxplot(x='Neighborhood', y='SalePrice', data=df_train)
sns.boxplot(x='OverallCond', y='SalePrice', data=df_train)

# CHART 4
fig.add_subplot(224)
#sns.violinplot(x = 'OverallQual', y = 'SalePrice', data=df_train, palette='Set3', bw=.2, cut=1, split=True, linewidth=1)
sns.boxplot(x='OverallQual', y='SalePrice', data=df_train)
```

Plot Result

[image: plot-result]

Already tried:

```py
ax.set_xticklabels(labels, rotation=45)
```

```py
ax.tick_params(labelrotation=45)
```

Comment: `ax` is the alias of a specific subplot, but you don’t have a subplot named `ax`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

One way to do this would be to get the axis for the specific plot (222 in your case) and then set the `tick_param()` to rotate label by 90 degrees. An example is shown below for your reference...

```
df_train = sns.load_dataset("titanic")
fig = plt.figure(figsize=(12, 8))

# CHART 1
fig.add_subplot(221)
#sns.countplot(df_train['MSZoning'])
sns.boxplot(x='sex', y='age', data=df_train)
                 
# CHART 2
fig.add_subplot(222)
#sns.boxplot(x='MSZoning', y='SalePrice', data=df_train)
ax222=sns.boxplot(x='embark_town', y='age', data=df_train) ## Note I added ax222

# CHART 3
fig.add_subplot(223)
#sns.boxplot(x='Neighborhood', y='SalePrice', data=df_train)
sns.boxplot(x='alive', y='age', data=df_train)

# CHART 4
fig.add_subplot(224)
#sns.violinplot(x = 'OverallQual', y = 'SalePrice', data=df_train, palette='Set3', bw=.2, cut=1, split=True, linewidth=1)
sns.boxplot(x='class', y='age', data=df_train)

## Rotate ax222 by 90 degrees
ax222.tick_params(axis='x', labelrotation=90)
```

**Output plot**

[image]